# Найти элемент без события.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как можно найти все элементы, которые не имеют события **onkeyup**?

Comment: Быть может вы имели введу не имеет подписчиков на событие?

Comment: Если события навешивались с помощью библиотеки - то получить такие данные можно. Библиотека, как правило, отслеживает проходящие через неё события. В нативном js отсутствует функция получения списка событий.

Comment: в идеале нужны те элементы, в которых вручную в теге прописали onkeyup

    <b href="" onkeyup=""></b>

Comment: @istem вы ошибаетесь, уже есть спецификация, хоть и новая:  

[http://EventListenerList][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html#Events-EventListenerList

Comment: Хмм. Спасибо. 
Цит: "не изменяйте объекты, которыми вы не владеете"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно выделить так:

```
$("element:not([onkeyup])")
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n84BB/).
Но это очень простой случай, когда событие задано через HTML. Если событие вешается через `on`, то можно написать свою обертку для `on`, например так:

```
function myLive(filter, event, func){
    $(filter).data("hasLiveEvent", true);
    $(filter).on(event, func);
};
```

Пример здесь http://jsfiddle.net/8cdez/1/
Но и в этом случае не получится выделить элементы, которые были созданы динамически, но можно самому задавать `data` при создании нового элемента.

Comment: @ReinRaus ага http://jsfiddle.net/n84BB/1/

Comment: @ReinRaus мне подошел, спасибо )

Answer (score 4):

```
$('*').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).data("events"));
});
```

Обновлено:

```
$('*').each(function() {
    if($._data(this, "events") == undefined) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: хм, тоже не работает.

Comment: обновил пост, в новых версиях jQuery убрали .data('events')